# Spacy "en_core_web_lg" model vectors giving wrong similarity output

Tags: string, vector, nlp, spacy

Just starting with NLP and following along a course on Udemy. I am trying to compute word similarity using cosine similarity of vectors.

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_lg')

# Choose the words you wish to compare, and obtain their vectors
word1 = nlp.vocab['wolf'].vector
word2 = nlp.vocab['dog'].vector
word3 = nlp.vocab['cat'].vector

# Import spatial and define a cosine_similarity function
from scipy import spatial

cosine_similarity = lambda x, y: 1 - spatial.distance.cosine(x, y)

# Write an expression for vector arithmetic
# For example: new_vector = word1 - word2 + word3
new_vector = word1 - word2 + word3

# List the top ten closest vectors in the vocabulary to the result of the expression above
computed_similarities = []

for word in nlp.vocab:
    if word.has_vector:
        if word.is_lower:
            if word.is_alpha:
                similarity = cosine_similarity(new_vector, word.vector)
                computed_similarities.append((word, similarity))

computed_similarities = sorted(computed_similarities, key=lambda item: -item[1])

print([w[0].text for w in computed_similarities[:10]])

['wolf', 'cat', 'i', 'cuz', 'dare', 'u', 'dog', 'she', 'ai', 'ca']
```

In the above output most of the words are not even close to the new vector.
Ideal output according to the tutor should be:

```
['maned', 'wolfs', 'wolf', 'lynx', 'wolve', 'yotes', 'canids', 'boars', 'foxes', 'wolfdogs']
```

Another problem is that when I am trying to compute for other words like king, man and queen the output is:

```
['king', 'woman', 'she', 'who', 'wolf', 'when', 'dare', 'cat', 'was', 'not']
```

instead of

```
['king','queen','commoner','highness','prince','sultan','maharajas','princes','kumbia','kings']
```

In this output words like "wolf" and "cat" are there since I ran the function on the above wolf,cat and dog example first. If I run the king,man and queen example after reloading the model, then "wolf" and "cat" are not there but some other unrelated words.

I have uninstalled and re-installed the model as well as recreated the environment but same result always. Am I doing something wrong? How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, the problem is not quality exactly, it is that the output of your code is different than what you are seeing on Udemy.

What is probably happening is that the Udemy tutor is using a different version of spaCy or a different model. You should confirm what version they're using and install the same one.

Comment: Yes the course is a couple of years old, and I am using the latest version of Spacy and the model. However if you look at my output, it is evident that the output is quite unexpected("i, cuz, dare") to the expected output(which I understand can be different from the instructors'). It so happens that when I run cosine similarity function individually on 2 words(eg, between woman and queen), its value comes closer to 1 than most of the output word values but the higher similarity word still does not show in output.